# How to call a string of multiple values ​from a ViewModel

Tags: android

I am trying to call a string that accepts two values ​​from a viewmodel

```
<string name="send_message">Se envió %1$s a %2$s</string>
```

with the next function

```
private fun getString(textId: Int,args: ArrayList<Any>) =
    getApplication<Application>().applicationContext?.getString(textId, args) ?: ""

    val message = getString(R.string.mystring, arrayListOf(amount,name))
```

But I get this error

> java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%2$s'

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by spreading but, varargs are more comfortable:

```
private fun getString(textId: Int,varargs args:Any!)
```

Besides, you should use AndroidViewModel() for access to the Context from your viewmodel, But! you'd better get this string in your fragment

Comment: Sorry, I was missing varargs, it works! thanks so much!